# A special definition of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, functional-equations

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $D:M_n(R)\to R$ be a function. We say that $D$ is a determinant if

- $D(B)=aD(A)$, whenever $B$ is obtained by multiplying a row of $A$ by $a$.
- If $A,B,C$ are identical except the $i$-th row, and $C_i=A_i+B_i$, where subscripts denote the $i$-th row vector, then $D(C)=D(A)+D(B)$.
- $D(A)=0$ if two rows of $A$ are identical.

Now, one can prove that if $D$ is a determinant and $D(I)=1$, then $D(A)D(B)=D(AB)$.

**The question is,** though, can I reverse this, and deduce that if $D$ satisfy $D(A)D(B)=D(AB)$, then $D$ is a determinant? This might not be true, so perhaps we need more assumptions.

PS: $D(I)=1$ can actually be proved from $D(A)D(B)=D(AB)$ if there exists $M$ such that $D(M)\neq 0$. Then $D(M)=D(MI)=D(M)D(I)$, so $D(I)=1$.

Comment: Are you also assuming $D(I)=1?$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That can actually be proved if there exists $M$ such that $D(M)\neq 0$. Then $D(M)=D(MI)=D(M)D(I)$, so $D(I)=1$.

Comment: Your argument for $D(I) = 1$ works only if $R$ is assumed to be an integral domain (or "$D(M) \neq 0$" is replaced by "$D(M)$ is a non-zero-divisor").

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $\sigma:R\to R$ be any function that is multiplicative but not additive. Then $D=\sigma\circ\det$ is multiplicative but it does not satisfy the requirement in your second bullet point.

E.g. let $R=\mathbb R$ and $\sigma(x)=x^2$, so that $D(A)=\det(A)^2$. Then $D$ is multiplicative, but
$$
0=D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)
\ne D\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)
+D\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)
=1+1.
$$

Comment: Note that when $R$ is a field, $n \geq 2$, and $n+|R|> 4$, then the solutions you give are the only ones. This is (mostly) because $SL_n(F)$ is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

No, take the function $D:M_n(R)\to R$ with $D(A)=1$ for all $A \in M_n(R).$  Clearly $D(AB)=1=1*1=D(A)D(B)$ but $D$ is not a determinant.